# record the computation time for each epoch in Keras during model.fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I want to compare the computation time between different models.
During the fit the computation time per epoch is printed to the console.

```
Epoch 5/5
160000/160000 [==============================] - **10s** ......
```

I'm looking for a way to store these times in a similar way to the model metrics that are saved in each epoch and avaliable through the history object.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try the following callback:

```
class TimeHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.times = []

    def on_epoch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.epoch_time_start = time.time()

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.times.append(time.time() - self.epoch_time_start)
```

Then:

```
time_callback = TimeHistory()
model.fit(..., callbacks=[..., time_callback],...)
times = time_callback.times
```

In this case `times` should store the epoch computation times.

Answer (score 20):

refer to answers of Marcin Możejko

```
import time

class TimeHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.times = []

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.epoch_time_start = time.time()

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.times.append(time.time() - self.epoch_time_start)
```

then

```
time_callback = TimeHistory()
model.fit(..., callbacks=[..., time_callback],...)
```

excution log

```
Train on 17000 samples, validate on 8000 samples
Epoch 1/3
17000/17000 [==============================] - 5s 266us/step - loss: 36.7562 - mean_absolute_error: 4.5074 - val_loss: 34.2384 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.3929
Epoch 2/3
17000/17000 [==============================] - 4s 253us/step - loss: 33.5529 - mean_absolute_error: 4.2956 - val_loss: 32.0291 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.2484
Epoch 3/3
17000/17000 [==============================] - 5s 265us/step - loss: 31.0547 - mean_absolute_error: 4.1340 - val_loss: 30.6292 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.1480
```

then

```
print(time_callback.times)
```

output

```
[4.531331300735474, 4.308278322219849, 4.505300283432007]
```

Comment: How do I also capture the time taken for validation data evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [Benjamin Striner](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5105#issuecomment-274182222) you could write a keras callback along the following lines

```
from time import time
class TimingCallback(Callback):
  def __init__():
    self.logs=[]
  def on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs={}):
    self.starttime=time()
  def on_epoch_end(epoch, logs={}):
    self.logs.append(time()-self.starttime)
...
cb = TimingCallback()
model.fit(..., callbacks=[cb])
print(cb.logs)
```