# Could I change the training time in keras from seconds to milliseconds?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, milliseconds

I am a beginner in `deep learning` and using `keras` backend `tensorflow`. I wonder if i could change the training time when my model do training like example below from seconds to milliseconds each epoch?

```
Epoch 195/5000
 - 0s - loss: 0.1007 - acc: 0.1803 - val_loss: 0.1226 - val_acc: 0.2145
```

Comment: To go from seconds to milliseconds you can just get the time value and multiply it by 1000.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres coud you teach me how to get the time value?

Comment: sure. You can create a callback to record the runtime of each epoch, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186440/5675325.