# Is there a way to plot a graph for the accuracy of a model against different time intervals?

Tags: python, keras, graph, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I would like to plot a graph for accuracy of different models at different time intervals.

For example let the accuracy of model is 95% at the time duration of 10 seconds and its accuracy is 96% after 20 seconds. Now I would like to plot a graph for this model.

is it possible to do so?

If yes please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you have a model:

`history = model.fit( ... )`

`history.history` should have the metric values for each epoch.

Then check this:
[record the computation time for each epoch in Keras during model.fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178668/record-the-computation-time-for-each-epoch-in-keras-during-model-fit) for getting completion times for each epoch

Comment: Thank you. This helped . But i want to plot the same for the built in classifier models like gaussian naive bayes, random forest, k nearest neighous,etc. How do i do it?